# What is meant by surface divergence of a vector function?

Tags: mathematical-physics, vectors, vector-fields

My book says:

> If there is a surface discontinuity in a vector field $\vec{E}$, we enclose it in a thin transitional layer (of width $h$) and apply divergence theorem. If $\hat{n}_1$ and $\hat{n}_2$ are outward normal vectors to the surface:
>
> $$\lim_\limits{h \to 0} \int_V \nabla \cdot \vec{E}\ dV
> = \oint_S (\vec{E}_1.\hat{n}_1 + \vec{E}_2.\hat{n}_2)\ dS
> = \oint_S \text{divs}\ \vec{E}\ dS$$

I do understand that the book calls (or defines):

$\text{divs}\ \vec{E}=\vec{E}_1.\hat{n}_1 + \vec{E}_2.\hat{n}_2$

What I don't understand is the relation between $(\text{divs}\ \vec{v}=\vec{v}_1.\hat{n}_1 + \vec{v}_2.\hat{n}_2)$ and $(\text{div}\ \vec{v})$. Why are they both called the divergence?

Comment: Typically we expect people to give the book title, author and page and equation reference numbers where possible.  It won't hurt and it can help sometimes.

Comment: Sorry about that....[Look here](https://archive.org/stream/ElectrodynamicsORahilly#page/n21/mode/1up)